# In below stored procedure for db2. I want to set the value of id fetch from db and use in second insert query

Tags: stored-procedures, db2

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE INSERT_LOCATION(
IN stockId VARCHAR (36),
IN locationName VARCHAR (50),
IN createdBy VARCHAR (25),
IN createdTstamp TIMESTAMP,
IN shipTo BIGINT,
IN aisleId VARCHAR (36),
IN aisleName VARCHAR(25),
IN cabinetId VARCHAR(36),
IN cabinetName VARCHAR(25),
IN shelfStart SMALLINT,
IN shelfEnd SMALLINT,
IN columnStart SMALLINT,
IN columnEnd SMALLINT
) 
BEGIN

    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT STOCKLOCATIONID
                   FROM EVMIDB.CI_STOCKLOC
                   WHERE SHIPTO = shipTo
                   and LOCATIONNAME= locationName ) THEN
           INSERT INTO EVMIDB.CI_STOCKLOC
                              (STOCKLOCATIONID
                              ,SHIPTO
                              ,LOCATIONNAME
                              ,CREATEDBY
                              ,CREATEDTIMESTAMP)
                          VALUES (stockId
                                 ,shipTo
                                 ,locationName
                                 ,createdBy
                                 ,createdTstamp);
    ELSE
         SET stockId=(SELECT STOCKLOCATIONID
                      FROM EVMIDB.CI_STOCKLOC
                      WHERE SHIPTO = shipTo
                      AND LOCATIONNAME= locationName
                      FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY);
    END IF;
    IF(aisleId !='') THEN
       IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT AISLEID
                      FROM EVMIDB.CI_AISLE
                      WHERE SHIPTO = shipTo
                      AND AISLENAME= aisleName ) THEN
              INSERT INTO EVMIDB.CI_AISLE(
                                 AISLEID
                                ,SHIPTO
                                ,AISLENAME
                                ,STOCKLOCATIONID)
                          values (aisleId
                                 ,shipTo
                                 ,aisleName
                                 ,stockId);
       ELSE
           SET aisleId=(SELECT AISLEID
                        FROM EVMIDB.CI_AISLE
                        WHERE SHIPTO = shipTo
                        and AISLENAME= aisleName
                        FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY);
       END IF;
    END IF;

    IF(cabinetId !='') THEN
        INSERT INTO EVMIDB.CI_CABINET
                          (CABINETID
                          ,SHIPTO
                          ,CABINETNAME
                          ,SHELFSTARTRANGE
                          ,SHELFENDRANGE
                          ,COLUMNSTARTRANGE
                          ,COLUMNENDRANGE
                          ,AISLEID)
                   values cabinetId,
                          shipTo,
                          cabinetName,
                          shelfStart,
                          shelfEnd,
                          columnStart,
                          columnEnd,
                          aisleId);
    END IF; 
END
```

I am not able to store the data in db as select query is not able to set the value from db so that i can use in another query. Can anybody help in writing this stored procedure? I am not able to find why it not storing in db2 for stock and aisle table .Only in cabinet table data is getting stored.

Comment: "Not able to store the data" or "not able to set the value from db" is not a correct description of the problem. What's the full error message you get?

Comment: Not able to store in stock and aisle table @MarkBarinstein . I am getting no error only cabinet data is getting stored

Comment: Seems that the problem is in the same names for table columns and parameters names. Use some prefix for parameter names like `p_mypar` instead of `mypar`, if you don't remember the identifier interpretation rules used in routines.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample case for your reference.

1. Save below as proc001 as plain text file.

```
drop procedure s1.p001@
create procedure s1.p001(
  IN num smallint default null
)
language sql
begin
  if not exists (select c1 from s1.t2) then
    set num=(select c1 from s1.t1);
  end if;

  if not exists (select c1 from s1.t2) then
    insert into s1.t2 (c1) values (num);
  end if;

  if not exists (select c1 from s1.t3) then
    insert into s1.t3 (c1) values (3);
  end if;
end
@
```

2. Save below as repro.sh, run "chmod 777 repro.sh" then execute it.

```
#!/bin/sh

db2 -v "drop db db1"
db2 -v "create db db1"
db2 -v "connect to db1"
db2 -v "create table s1.t1 (c1 int)"
db2 -v "create table s1.t2 (c1 int)"
db2 -v "create table s1.t3 (c1 int)"
db2 -v "insert into s1.t1 values (1)"

# create stored procedure
db2 -td@ -vf proc001

# execute it
db2 -v "call S1.P001()"

db2 -v "select * from s1.t1"
db2 -v "select * from s1.t2"
db2 -v "select * from s1.t3"
db2 -v "terminate"
```

3. Repro.sh's three select statements return as below:

```
select * from s1.t1
   ==>    1
select * from s1.t2
   ==>    1
select * from s1.t3
   ==>    3
```

As above, could set the value from a column and use it in second insert.

Hope this helps.